# Obtaining transition properties in TALES expression

Tags: workflow, plone

I've created a custom workflow in Plone, using Products.DCWorkflow. I've set the transition descriptions to a more verbose description of what just occurred and am trying to display them in a status message. I thought I would be able to do this using workflow variables, but I'm hitting what appears to be a permissions issue and don't understand why.

I've based my workflow on `simple_publication_workflow`, which provides a set of variables. I tried copying the approach used for the `action` variable, which has a default expression of `transition/getId|nothing`. I created an `action_description` variable, and added `transition/description|nothing`. With this, I get a `None` value returned. Without the `|nothing` option, the page redirects to `https`, indicating the user doesn't have the permissions required for a current action.

I've put a breakpoint into `createExprContext` in `Products/DCWorkflow/Expression.py`, and as the same user I can see the information I want in `sci.transition.description`. So I tried replacing the previous default expression with `python:transition.description`, but I get the same apparent permission problem.

I'm wondering why this is happening? Why is `transition/getId` a valid expression for a workflow variable, while `transition/description` is not?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I fear you are facing some problem with the restricted environment. If you take a look at the `Transition` class definition, you'll see that there's a define method `getId` but no accessor for `description`.
You can also see a `declareObjectProtected` call. I fear that accessing to all attributes is restricted.

Comment: @keul Thanks, that's what I thought after poking through DCWorkflow a bit further. It seems really odd to provide a system for custom variables and then heavily restrict what can be done with it. I ended up just grabbing the description via the workflow tool in the view itself, I was just kind of hoping I wouldn't have to double-touch the workflow data.